# Is there any difference between “exquisite” and “excellent”?

Tags: differences, synonyms

For example I could say

> The city has an excellent public transport system.

Could I also say the following?

> The city has an exquisite public transport system.

To my ears the second one sounds wrong. Is it wrong?  If it is can someone explain what is the difference between the two
 words?

Comment: Perhaps if you were in Lothlórien.

Comment: An ***excellent** public transport system* is far more likely, particularly if you're praising the *day-to-day performance* of the system. But an ***exquisite** public transport system* is perfectly credible if, say, you want to focus on the *intricate design* of the network. This sort of distinction can be established from dictionaries.

Comment: Just Monday I was experiencing excellent pain, following shoulder surgery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exquisite**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exquisite?s=t

The word describes the finer things in life; beautiful, charming, attractive and fine, always fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the *new oxford american dictionary*, exquisite means *extremely beautiful and, typically, delicate* but excellent means *extremely good; outstanding*.

So, excellent is broader than exquisite.

Comment: You've never seen an exquisite broad?

Answer (score -1):

The second usage is indeed strange considering that **exquisite** is usually reserved for things of the finest craftsmanship and of remarkable beauty.  For example, the Faberge Eggs are described as exquisite.  Also, jewelry http://www.exquisitejewelers.com, and watches http://www.exquisitetimepieces.com.

[image]

Perhaps Faberge has reincarnated and designed the transport system...

[image]

See **excellent**, here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/excellent.  You can call exquisite things excellent but excellent doesn't really call to mind the intricacy and wonder that exquisite does.

When Hamlet was talking with Rosenkrantz and Gildenstern he said, "*What a piece of work is a man, how noble in reason, how infinite in faculties, in form and moving, how express and admirable in action, how like an angel in apprehension, how like a god!*"  He could have slipped the word ***exquisite*** in; "What an exquisite piece of work is a man..."

Comment: But does your picture above not show an exquisite transportation system?

Comment: @HotLicks that's funny...

Comment: But true.  And it's easy to see how a transportation system which was much better than it's peers (clean, well-run, etc), especially in years gone by, might be called "exquisite".

Comment: It's definitely in the mind of the beholder.  But I feel sorry for anyone who cannot identify some exquisite aspect of even the most mundane item -- they get their intellectual nourishment from McDonald's.